# How to analyse the survey to understand how answer to one question impacts rest

Tags: powerbi, analytics

I have a survey data with 5 Question

1.) Whom yu are living with : girlfriend, wife

2.) If the person healthy : yes, no, partially

3.) Is the person working : Yes, No

4.) Are you happy with the person : Yes, No, Cant Say

5.) If the person owns a house : yes, no

I want to analyse one answer impacts the rest of the answers.  For eg. how many of perople living with wife who has house and are happy. The requirement is to analyse these answers along each other.

The data collected is this format below. Please suggest what would be the best way to analyse the data in such fashion.

UserId  Question    Answer
1   Whom yu are living with Wife
1   If the person healthy   Yes
1   Is the person working   No
1   Are you happy with the person   Yes
1   If the person owns a house  No
2   Whom yu are living with Girlfriend
2   If the person healthy   Partial
2   Is the person working   Yes
2   Are you happy with the person   Yes
2   If the person owns a house  No
3   Whom yu are living with Wife
3   If the person healthy   Yes
3   Is the person working   yes
3   Are you happy with the person   No
3   If the person owns a house  Yes

I initially thought of to create a tree map with Questions and Answers and use drill through the open second page with tree map filtered on the user id. But later i realized that the drill through could use the filters which are not part of the parent chart.

Than i thought of using parameters like SSRS, but power bi has limitation to have only one value to the parameters.

What i am looking for is a descent way to analyse this data. Or a workaround on the two possible options i tried to remove roadblocks.

I am open to any different way to analyse the data then i am doing if it answers the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple one, but as long as you are not planning on doing statistical analysis and just want to explore the data, maybe create 5 bar charts with the category of the X and a count on the Y and use the build in interactions by clicking on different categories to gain a basic understanding.

Comment: that makes sense for single survey, but client has multiple surveys with different number of questions. They want a survey slicer at the top such that they do not have to develop new report for each survey

Comment: So it's not limited to the five questions in your question? What does your data look like? Does each question has its own column for instance?